# C++ - using enums to generate a deck of cards

Tags: c++, enums

I have just started learning C++, and am still new to the concepts of header files and the structure of classes. I have been learning Java for 2 years and the C++ syntax and some operations have different behaviors.

I am trying to make a deck of cards. To make the code cleaner, I would like to use enumerations for my Suits and Values of the cards. However the problem in the Deck class is that I have a method to populate the deck with cards using a `vector`.

I have researched and I now realize in c++ you cant iterate over enumerations. Everywhere I look people suggest using enumerations but avoid the question of how could I possibly populate the deck if I cant iterate through enumerations.

I have a Card header file and class as follows:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card
{
public:
    enum Suit{ HEARTS, CLUBS, SPADES, DIAMONDS };
    enum Value{TWO ,THREE ,FOUR ,FIVE ,SIX ,SEVEN ,
                EIGHT , NINE , TEN ,ACE,KING,QUEEN,JACK};

    Card(Suit suit, Value value);
    ~Card();

    Suit GetSuit();
    void SetSuit(Suit suit);
    Value GetValue();
    void SetValue(Value value);
private:
    Suit m_cardSuit;
    short m_cardValue;
};

#endif 

#include "Card.h"


Card::Card(Suit suit,short value){
    this->m_cardSuit = suit;
    this->m_cardValue = value;
}

void Card::SetSuit(Suit suit){
    this->m_cardSuit = suit;
}

//this is needed to get enum from .h class!!
Card::Suit Card::GetSuit(){
    return m_cardSuit;
}

short Card::GetValue(){
    return m_cardValue;
}

void Card::SetValue(short value){
    this->m_cardValue = value;
}
```

And a Deck header and class as follows:

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"

using namespace std;
class Deck
{
public:
    Deck();
    Card GetCard(Card& card);
    void addCard(Card& card);
    void shuffleCards();
    vector<Card> drawCards(short cardsToDraw);
    void PopulateDeck();
    ~Deck();

private:
    vector <Card>* m_pCards;
    short m_NumberOfCards;
    short m_MaximumNumberOfCards;
    Card m_card;
};
#endif

#include "Deck.h"


Deck::Deck()
{
    m_MaximumNumberOfCards = 52;
    m_NumberOfCards = 0;
    m_pCards = new vector<Card>(52);    //creates heap space for 52 cards.
    PopulateDeck();
}


Deck::~Deck()
{

}

void Deck::addCard(Card& cardToAdd){
    m_pCards->push_back(cardToAdd); //add a card to the deck. same as (*m_pCards).cardToAdd
}

void Deck::PopulateDeck(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            Card card(Card::Suit.[j],Card::Value.[i]);
            m_pCards->push_back(card);
        }
}
```

I know the syntax in the `PopulateDeck()` method is incorrect. But this is the problem I am trying to solve.

Is it possible to create cards and add them to the deck in a similar manner or will I have to go another route and use arrays instead?

Comment: [OT]: use directly `std::vector <Card>` instead of pointer on `std::vector`.

Comment: I am not sure about the values of the cards, but will they have all consecutive values as in JACK = 11, QUEEN = 12, KING = 13, ACE = 14 ...? Otherwise iterating through the enum will become difficult.

Comment: @Jarod42: Unfortunately I want to learn some memory allocation so the pointer I made for the cards is to make a vector of cards out on the heap,as I said if I am going about doing that the wrong way please correct me. But I do want to have the cards on the heap.

Comment: @ChirsG yes they will all have consecutive values, will this help me in the matter?

Comment: @ChirsG sorry thats a mistake in my code, I actually have removed value allocations so my code now is {TWO,THREE,FOUR ....ect}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may directly do:

```
void Deck::PopulateDeck(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            Card card(j, i);
            // Or Card card(Card::Suit(j), Card::Value(i))
            m_pCards->push_back(card);
        }
    }
}
```

Or, with strong type:

```
enum class Suit{ Begin, HEARTS = Begin, CLUBS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, End };
enum class Value{
    Begin, TWO = Begin, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN,
    JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE, End
};

Card::Suit& operator ++(Card::Suit& e)
{
    e = Card::Suit(int(e) + 1);
    return e;
}

Card::Value& operator ++(Card::Value& e)
{
    e = Card::Value(int(e) + 1);
    return e;
}

void Deck::PopulateDeck(){
    for (Card::Value i = Card::Value::Begin; i != Card::Value::End; ++i) {
        for (Card::Suit j = Card::Suit::Begin; j != Card::Suit::End; ++j){
            Card card(j, i);
            m_cards.push_back(card);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a45b324236aa9f9d)

Comment: Nice use of `begin` and `end`s in the enum class! +1

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the reply! I tried to do the first recommendation but it wont allow me to add it to the vector. It's saying it doesnt match the argument type. As for the second approach, I am not fully aware of what your doing there. Are they all held in a separate class? Or are they all stored in the Deck class. Sorry for the confusion I am very new to the structure of c++ and come from a java background.

Comment: For the first approach, I think you have problem with your current code:
`new vector<Card>(52)` creates a vector with 52 default cards (requires default constructor for card that you don't have), that is not what you want. You want a vector, (possibly `reserve` its size to 52 for optimization), then add 52 specific cards. so `m_pCards = new vector<Card>;` and then `m_pCards->push_back(card);`.

Comment: For the second approach, I enforce strong type for your `enum` to disallow implicit conversion enum/int (so I hava to add `++` for the enum, whereas before the implicit conversion helps). Whereas it makes sense to have strong type for `Suit`. For value (depending of the game), you may want an implicit conversion int/enum as *Jack* may be see as `11` with an other name (and so ordering your enum would be important). I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks very much! Really appreciate your response. It's clearer to me now. Have much more appreciation for those of you who code in c++! Java has never looked so kind!