# Structuring and generating a deck of cards with a loop in c++

Tags: c++, blackjack

it's in c++

The idea was to set it up so that it will keep looping through all the cards to keep getting different results and answers until all 52 cards are gone i dont know the exact placmet for it I know its

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
   {
     cout << i << endl;
   }
```

I wasn't quite sure how to set up the array If I just did it like string {ace, one two} and so on.. but I have the array labeled 52 even typing them all out its only 13 number repeated 4 times in 4 suits so would you class them all separately? Or is there something for that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class cardGame;

int main()
{
    int bet;
    int dealer[52] = { 13, 13, 13, 13 };
    int player[52] = { 13, 13, 13, 13 };
    int dealerCard1;
    int dealerCard2;
    int playerCard1;
    int playerCard2;
    int dealerTotal;
    int playerTotal;
    int shuffle;

    cout << "This is My attempt at BlackJack" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> bet;
    cout << "Player enter amount to bet: $ ";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> shuffle;

    cardGame::playeer(playerCard1 + playerCard2 = playerTotal);
    cardsGame.playerCard1 = 0;
    cardsGame.playerCard2 = 0;
    cardsGame.playerTotal = 0;


    cout << "the First card is: " << cardsGame.playerCard1 = 0 << endl;
    cout << "The second card is: " << cardsGame.playerCard = 0 << endl;
    cout << "Your total is: " << cardsGame.playerTotal = 0 << endl;
    cardGame::playeer(playerCard1 + playerCard2 = playerTotal);

    if (playerCard1 + playerCard2 == 21)
    {
        cout << "WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!" << endl;
    };
    else (playerCard1 + playerCard2 > 21)
    {
        cout << "What a dissapointment you are to everyone!" << endl;
    };
    if (playerCard1 + playerCard2 > dealerTotal)
    {
        cout << "WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!" << endl;
    };
    else (playerCard1 + playerCard2 == dealerTotal)
    {
        cout << "What a dissapointment you are to everyone!"
    }


    cardGame::dealer(dealerCard1 + dealerCard2 = dealerTotal);
    cardsGame.dealerCard1 = 0;
    cardsGame.dealerCard2 = 0;
    cardsGame.dealerTotal = 0;



    cout << "the First card is: " << cardsGame.dealerCard1 = 0 << endl;
    cout << "The second card is: " << cardsGame.dealerCard2 = 0 << endl;
    cout << "Your total is: " << cardsGame.dealerTotal = 0 << endl;
    cardGame::dealer(dealerCard1 + playerCard2 = playerTotal);

    if (dealerCard1 + dealerCard2 == 21)
    {
        cout << "What a dissapointment you are to everyone!" << endl;
    };
    else (dealerCard1 + dealerCard2 > 21)
    {
        cout << "WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER" << endl;
    }
    if (dealerCard1 + dealerCard2 > playerTotal)
    {
        cout << "What a dissapointment you are to everyone!" << cout endl:
    };
    else (dealerCard1 + dealerCard2 < playerTotal)
    {
        cout << "What a dissapointment you are to everyone!"
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello - welcome to SO! Can you please add tags to indicate which programming language you are using?

Comment: Also, you need to be more specific about the problem you're having and selective about your code sample - what is the purpose of the loop you're trying to add?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - using enums to generate a deck of cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937285/c-using-enums-to-generate-a-deck-of-cards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know c++ (or blackjack); but below is an example **in Javascript** which illustrates some concepts and might push you in the right direction.

In terms of structure you might want something like:

```
// Set up your 'deck'

deck = {
  hearts: [],
  spades: [],
  diamonds: [],
  clubs: []
}

// The object 'deck' has four properties (hearts, spades...), each of which is an empty array.

// Use a loop to add your 'cards'

Object.keys(deck).forEach(suit => {
  for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    deck[suit].push(i);
  }
});

// For each property in the object 'deck', push ascending consecutive integers starting from the number 1 to each array, until the number 14 is reached.
```

This gives you:

```
deck = {
  hearts: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
  spades: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
  diamonds: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
  clubs: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
}
```

Comment: oh ok ya so I shoudl seperate them... Thank you

Comment: tryingg to figure out how but i will

Comment: Thanks! It's the up arrow and the check mark at the top left of my answer

Comment: M bbn m n.v cx .f.. my